# Opengraph css in Facebook description as in attached image

Tags: facebook-opengraph

wondering how the "Breaking 1 Hr" icon is achieved in the attached screenshot. I have looked everywhere and on other forums but no one has been able to help.

Thanks in advance. [Screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld0Gv.png)

Comment: I don't quite see your question. Do you want CSS for similar icon? Or do you want to know how to achieve it on FB?

Comment: please add the link in question. this is quite broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry about the vague question. - I wanted to know how they achieved the Breaking 1hr icon when sharing links on Facebook. I don't actually want mine to say Breaking or even look like this, I just want to know how it is done.

Comment: Also I just checked their Facebook and there are no other posts displaying the icon today. There have been in the past just nothing today so there is no link to share.

Comment: Here is a link with the Breaking Icon showing when shared. Not sure how long it will remain. Thanks https://www.9news.com.au/2018/09/19/19/02/peter-dutton-au-pair-senate-inquiry-no-confidence-motion?ocid=Social-9News

I have saved the page source info if that helps.